# Better asynchronous control flow with Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I'm using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for asynchronous calls to a web service. Some of these calls must be chained together, where the results of call A are used by call B which are used by call C, etc.

AFNetworking handles results of async calls with success/failure blocks set at the time the operation is created:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Public Timeline: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

This results in nested async call blocks which quickly becomes unreadable. It's even more complicated when tasks are not dependent on one another and instead must execute in parallel and execution depends on the results of all operations.

It seems that a better approach would be to leverage a [promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) framework to clean up the control flow.

I've come across [MAFuture](https://github.com/mikeash/MAFuture) but can't figure out how best to integrate it with AFNetworking. Since the async calls could have multiple results (success/failure) and don't have a return value it doesn't seem like an ideal fit.

Any pointers or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for this question – you've got some great answers. I had a little trouble finding it initially though, and got here via looking at promises. This anti-pattern can happen for any asynchronous callback API: it's not AFNetworking specific. I was using a search something like: "serialising nested block callbacks". Maybe some more tags could help? It could just be me though! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't used it yet, but it sounds like [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/blog/1107-reactivecocoa-for-a-better-world) was designed to do just what you describe.

Comment: I have used it, and Jon is right. it's great for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Interesting. I'd come across Reactive Cocoa but didn't consider it for this scenario. Since the AF operations are all KVO compliant I could add handlers to either the operation queue or the individual operations. I'll mess with that.

Comment: I like the ReactiveCocoa approach. My [blog article](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/managing-nested-asynchronous-callbacks-in-objective-c-using-reactive-cocoa/) explains how to use ReactiveCocoa for this purpose.

Answer (score 19):

I created a light-weight solution for this. It's called Sequencer and it's up on [github](https://github.com/berzniz/Sequencer).

It makes chaining API calls (or any other async code) easy and straightforward.

Here's an example of using AFNetworking with it:

```
Sequencer *sequencer = [[Sequencer alloc] init];

[sequencer enqueueStep:^(id result, SequencerCompletion completion) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        completion(JSON);
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
}];

[sequencer enqueueStep:^(NSDictionary *feed, SequencerCompletion completion) {
    NSArray *data = [feed objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSDictionary *lastFeedItem = [data lastObject];
    NSString *cononicalURL = [lastFeedItem objectForKey:@"canonical_url"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cononicalURL]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        completion(responseObject);
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
}];

[sequencer enqueueStep:^(NSData *htmlData, SequencerCompletion completion) {
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"HTML Page: %@", html);
    completion(nil);
}];

[sequencer run];
```

Comment: That's a nice neat, simple solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Looks like in the case of an error in step 1 or 2, the rest of the steps won't be executed.

Comment: @fabb I believe that's the desired outcome here – it's certainly the effect I want to achieve.

Comment: @fabb In the example code above, `nil` is passed in as the failure block, so errors are silently ignored (but error _do_ cause the sequencer to halt and be disposed of, because nothing calls the next step). In my code, I have an error handler block available to the function that is running the `Sequencer`. I pass this error handler instead of the `nil`. If there _is_ an error, I don't want the remaining steps to run. I want the error block to be called immediately and the sequencer will just get thrown away at the point it reached.

Comment: Ok, so Sequencer is a "half" implementation of a Promise then?

Comment: @fabb :-) I'm not sure what a Promise is, to be honest. The Sequencer here is really _just_ (quite literally) a queue of tasks that you want to run. Its main conveniences are that it "thinks about" what the next task is for you (by popping it from the front of the queue), and provides a simple interface to pass a parameter forward to the next step.

Comment: I like this solution a lot. In my code, as discussed with @fabb, I've got a single error handler block I can pass to the asynchronous calls where needed (or I can wrap it when the calls have a different error block interface). **A "tip" for passing more data forward to future steps**. Sometimes you have data you need to pass forward several steps. A clean and easy way to achieve this is to declare a `__block` variable **before** a step (at function scope), assign to it **in** a step, and **use** the variable in a future step.

Comment: @Benjohn I highly recommend you learning about promises. There are 2 very good iOS libraries I know that also have excellent documentation and introduction to Promises: https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise and http://promisekit.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67922/discussion-between-benjohn-and-fabb).

Comment: It seems like Sequencer only allows waterfall-like controls and not customizable for doing things in parallel.

Answer (score 10):

It was not uncommon when using AFNetworking in Gowalla to have calls chained together in success blocks.

My advice would be to factor the network requests and serializations as best you can into class methods in your model. Then, for requests that need to make sub-requets, you can call those methods in the success block.

Also, in case you aren't using it already, `AFHTTPClient` greatly simplifies these kinds of complex network interactions.

Comment: Thanks @mattt. That's basically what I'm doing now. The nested blocks just have a sense of code smell. It's the same smell I get with deeply nested conditional logic. Perhaps I'm longing for some of the cleanliness that node.js and other Javascript frameworks offer to make for more readable functional programming.

Comment: The deep nesting is not an inherent result of this approach--by effectively factoring callbacks into their own methods, it should look a lot more like chaining in a functional language. Having to go deeper than two nested calls is definitely a smell, though, and it probably means that you should consider creating a new API call to get you what you need all at once (if that's in your power at all)

Answer (score 6):

[PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/) could be useful. It seems to be one of the more popular promise implementations, and others have written categories to integrate it with libraries like AFNetworking, see [PromiseKit-AFNetworking](https://github.com/csotiriou/PromiseKit-AFNetworking).

Answer (score 4):

There is an Objective-C implementation of CommonJS-style promises here on Github:

https://github.com/mproberts/objc-promise

Example (taken from the Readme.md)

```
Deferred *russell = [Deferred deferred];
Promise *promise = [russell promise];

[promise then:^(NSString *hairType){
    NSLog(@"The present King of France is %@!", hairType);
}];

[russell resolve:@"bald"];

// The present King of France is bald!
```

I haven't yet tried out this library, but it looks 'promising' despite this slightly underwhelming example. (sorry, I couldn't resist).

Comment: Looks like it could be very useful but it's not ARC compliant and I don't have the wherewithal to make it so {sigh}.

Comment: This commit appears to have made it ARC compliant: https://github.com/mproberts/objc-promise/commit/9bdeac0d6b1305f00c9c3e4c64bef2743536ed9a

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `NSBlockOperation` with `semaphore` to achieve it:

```
- (void)loadDataByOrderSuccess:(void (^)(void))success failure:(void (^)(void))failure {
    // first,load data1
    NSBlockOperation * operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [self loadData1Success:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        } failure:^{
            !failure ?: failure();
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }];
    // then,load data2
    NSBlockOperation * operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [self loadData2Success:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        } failure:^{
            !failure ?: failure();
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }];
    // finally,load data3
    NSBlockOperation * operation3 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [self loadData3Success:^{
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        } failure:^{
            !failure ?: failure();
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        !success ?: success();
    }];
    [operation2 addDependency:operation1];
    [operation3 addDependency:operation2];
    NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperations:@[operation1, operation2, operation3] waitUntilFinished:NO];
}
```