# How to chain multiple AFNetworking calls to each run after the previous has finished successfully?

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

The following method uses AFNetworking to send a request to a webservice and (when successful) acts upon the response. AFNetworking does the request asynchronously and uses blocks for success or failure. So the method to send the request looks something like this (simplified):

```
- (void)sendRequestForConnector:(NSString *)connector 
          success:(void (^)(NSData *responseXml))success
          failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationForConnector:connector];
  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
  {
    [self handleSuccessForConnector:connector response:[operation responseData]];
    success([operation responseData]);
  } 
  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
  {
    [self handleFailureForConnector:connector error:error];
    failure(error);
  }

  [operation start];
}
```

In another class this method is used to call the webservice multiple times. When the previous call was successful, the next call is done. This method looks something like this (failure blocks omitted for brevity):

```
- (void)import 
{
   [client sendRequestForConnector:@"cities" success:^{
     [client sendRequestForConnector:@"categories" success:^{
       [client sendRequestForConnector:@"categoryTranslations" success:^{
         [client sendRequestForConnector:@"products" success:^{
           [client sendRequestForConnector:@"productTranslations" success:^{

             [self finishImport];

           }];
         }];
       }]; 
     }];
   }];
}
```

This works, but as one can see, each webservice call adds another nested success block handler. It seems to me there must be a nicer way to do this, but I can't think of one.

Preferably, I want to wait for the previous call to be completed before I do the next call and use something like GCD to call the whole import method asynchronously. However, AFNetworking is not designed to make synchronous calls.

Any ideas how to achieve this are greatly welcomed. Or is my current solution the way to go?

Comment: Have the same issue, did you find any good solutions for this? thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this. Where I have succeeding requests dependent on the results of the previous request.

Answer (score 3):

I was in same situation where i need to wait for response and need to call ws  for upload after completed last upload ,

there are several ways to do this

1) You can use `dispatch_group` and notify when you finished all.

2) Call ws one by one with create semaphores

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    dispatch_semaphore_t test = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.uploadDocument.count; ++i) {
       // My custom method with block which call ws 
      [self uploadMultipleImagesUsingAFNetworkingMultipartFormatWithDocumentId:[[self.uploadDocument objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:kDocument_DocumentId] andIndex:i withCompletionBlock:^(id responseObj, NSError *error) {

            // Your Logic 

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(test);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(test, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // Here comes when your all ws finish 
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              [self.tblUpload reloadData];
              [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        });
    }
```

Comment: If you needs to chain several calls and the current call depends on the success of the previous one this solution may not work

Comment: i think it should work because it will wait till other response come and signal semaphore , i am using it and working , still you can give me suggestion to improve this, thnx for your comment

Comment: So you may try my solution as well :D

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at `octokit`. They combine AFNetworking with Mantle and ReactiveCocoa - chaining works easily and cleanly with ReactiveCocoa.

https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look at this answer [Better asynchronous control flow with Objective-C blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915927/better-asynchronous-control-flow-with-objective-c-blocks)

A few custom solutions are suggested to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and have been thinking about introducing [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/abstracting-away-asynchronicity/) & [AFNetworking-PromiseKit](https://github.com/csotiriou/AFNetworking-PromiseKit) for a while. But I finally gave up and come up with a simple and somewhat kludge solution,

So I introduced a property called "step", the main purpose to kvo it. Then for each asynchronous call when it finishes it needs to mark its step. The kvo method will then move the whole process to next step, i.e. **the kvo method does the flow control.**

For example, your sendRequestForConnector:@"cities" will be step 1, @"categories" be step 2, @"categoryTranslations" be step 3, @"products" be step 4 ...  at the end of each success block set the step to its own value. So kvo will know this step is finished and it needs to call the next asynchronous method.

The kvo method oversee and controls the whole process.

```
switch (step.intValue) {
    case 1: //call step2; break;
    case 2: //call step3; break;
    case 3: //call step4; break;
    case 4: //call step5; break;
    ...
    case x: // finish, remove kvo on step
}
```

So far it serves my purpose and my codes do look much cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make synchronous calls then just use NSString's "stringWithContentsOfURL:" method. So just loop through an NSArray of NSURL's with this code in your loop.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* htmlSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theNSURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) {
    // handle error
}
// parse htmlSource
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Sometimes instead of answering a question you suggest an alternative approach that would better help the poster accomplish his goals. He wants synchronous calls so there's no reason to use blocks and modify a custom class meant for asynchronous calls. A simple NSString method can do it. If he doesn't want it to block the main thread while it's operating then just run the NSString method on a background thread (again, a simple one-line piece of code). He could even post a notification when complete and the main thread can receive the notification and perform some post operation if necessary.