# Handle concurrency and asynchronous response

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I am trying to implement concurrency in `objective C`.  I have a problem with an actions that needs to be run in a  synchronized way. The problem here is that I use function that executes a block after completion.

I want to connect to a bluetooth device to run some operations and connect to the next device.

```c
for (Beacon * beacon in beacons) {
    [beacon setDelegate:self];
    [beacon connectToBeacon];
}
```

But the connection is asynchronous. The beacon call the delegate (in this case it's the same class) method `didConnectSuccess` when connection is successful.

I need to wait all my operations in "`beaconDidConnect`" and deconnection to finish before connecting to the next device.

I currently use a combination of dispatch queue and dispatch semaphore, my semaphore is an ivar

```c
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);

for (Beacon * beacon in beacons) {
    [beacon setDelegate:self];
    dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreBluetooth, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [beacon connectToBeacon];

    });
}
```

In combination with

```c
- (void)beaconDidDisconnect:(Beacon *)beacon
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoreBluetooth);
}
```

Without the dispatch_async, by blocking the callback (beaconDidConnect), the wait was causing a deadlock.
I wanted to `dispatch_semaphore_wait` in the for loop and not in the dispatch block but the wait causes the callback to wait again, causing a deadlock.

This way it seems to work but I found it a bit ugly.

My other issue is that in my `beaconDidConnect` method I need to chain `asynchronous` call and in each waiting the previous to terminate.

All those calls have a termination block, executing when the call is done. I could write instructions in deeper and deeper block but I'd like to avoid this.

I'd need an equivalent of the javascript "promise" concept.

Currently I have something with dispatch queue and dispatch semaphore but I sometimes have deadlock for unknown reason.

Eg :

```c
- (void)beaconConnectionDidSucceeded:(Beacon *)beacon
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphoreEditing = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    dispatch_queue_t editingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue.Editing", NULL);

    // First writing procedure
    dispatch_async(editingQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreEditing, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [beacon writeSomeCaracteristic:caracteristic withValue:value withCompletion:^(void) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoreEditing);
        }];
    });

    // A unknow number of writing sequences
    dispatch_async(editingQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreEditing, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [beacon writeSomeCaracteristic:caracteristic withValue:value withCompletion:^(void) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoreEditing);
        }];
    });
    //
    // ...
    // 
    dispatch_async(editingQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreEditing, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [beacon writeSomeCaracteristic:caracteristic withValue:value withCompletion:^(void) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoreEditing);
        }];
    });    

    // Terminate the edition
    dispatch_async(editingQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphoreEditing, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [beacon disconnectBeacon];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphoreEditing);
    });
}
```

I want to write clear code that execute my instructions in a sequential way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept the dispatch_queue and dispatch_semaphore for the connection but for the writing actions I use a library called [Sequencer](https://github.com/berzniz/Sequencer) I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915927/better-asynchronous-control-flow-with-objective-c-blocks).

It follows the Promises principle CouchDeveloper talked about.

Answer (score 2):

If your asynchronous methods do have a completion handler, you can "serialize" or "chain" a number of asynchronous calls like shown below:

```
[self asyncFooWithCompletion:^(id result){
    if (result) {
        [self asyncBarWithCompletion:^(id result){
            if (result) {
                 [self asyncFoobarWithCompletion:^(id result){
                     if (result) {
                         ...
                     }
                 }];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Of course, this gets increasingly confusing with the number of chained asynchronous calls, and especially when you want to handle errors, too.

With a third party library which especially helps to overcome these problems (including error handling, cancellation) it may look similar as the code below:

Given:

```
- (Promise*) asyncFoo;
- (Promise*) asyncBar;
- (Promise*) asyncFoobar;
```

"Chaining" the three asynchronous methods including error handling:

```
[self asyncFoo]
.then(^id(id result){
    ... // do something with result of asyncFoo
    return [self asyncBar];
}, nil)
.then(^id (id result){
    ... // do something with result of asyncBar
    return [self asyncFoobar];
}, nil)
.then(^id(id result) {
    ... // do something with result of asyncFoobar
    return nil;
},
^id(NSError*error){
    // "catch" any error from any async method above
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return nil;
});
```

For general info about "Promises", please read wiki article [Futures and Promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises).

There are number of Objective-C libraries which implement a Promise.

Comment: I have thought to this solution but I thought there were a more idiomatic way of doing these things in ObjectiveC.
Thanks !

Comment: I think it is "idiomatic" ;)   Unfortunately, Objective-C has no built-in features to express asynchronous programming style, like an "async" or "yield" keyword like in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue?

If you need to wait for every beacon to run a set of operations before continue, you can store every set of operations in a NSOperation and put all the operations inside a NSOperationQueue with a maxConcurrentLimit of 1. It might be easier to cancel/pause/terminate every single operation and the queue will take care of the concurrency.